# How to get STATIC library default by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project integrated bt third-party project. One of it use

```
add_library(json 
  dist/jsoncpp.cpp
  dist/json/json.h
  dist/json/json-forwards.h)
```

no `STATIC` or `SHARED` used. When I build it not as third-party library but build it directly, it will produce a static library. But when I integrated it as third-party, it will produce a shared library. This will cause an error like:

```
Linking CXX shared library ThirdParty\ozz-animation\src\animation\offline\tools\json\json_d.dll
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: can't open the file “ThirdParty\ozz-animation\src\animation\offline\tools\json\json_d.lib”
```

I know adding `STATIC` to `add_library()` will fixed the problem. But I use **git submodule** to manage it.
I don't want to fork the project and sync every time.

Is there any way to make it be a static library in the upper-layer CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Add `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` to the CMake command line to build shared libs, `OFF` to build static libs. No need to change the downloaded project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to add the variable `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` ([read about it in the official CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html)) to your CMake call setting it to `FALSE`, `0` or `OFF`.

So, if your `CMakeLists.txt` file is in the parent directory, you need to call CMake using:

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..`

You can force it from your `CMakeLists.txt` file but I wouldn't recommend you to do that since it can produce problems if your CMake toolchain files are expecting something different.

Answer (score 0):

In `CMakeLists.txt`

As a variable:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)
```

As an option to tick on/off

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build libraries as SHARED" FALSE)
```